# Running gradle tasks from a subproject with unknown root

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have a multi-project setup in gradle with a somewhat-flat structure like so:

```
RootProject/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle

SubProjectA/
    build.gradle

anotherDirectory/
    SubProjectB/
        build.gradle
    SubProjectC/
        build.gradle
```

The root project is really just a root build. It's there to tie all of the other projects together. SubProjectB depends on SubProjectC, and C depends on A.

Running tasks from the root project works as expected. I can run `gradle :SubProjectB:build` and it will build SubProjectB and its dependencies without error.

My problem is that if I try to run a task from a sub-project's directory, it fails if that sub-project depends on any of the other sub-projects because it doesn't know where any of the others are without the root project's settings file. So running A's build from its directory would work, but running B's or C's would fail.

Is there anything I can do within this structure to define what the root project actually is, so that if I run `gradle build` from B, it would behave the same as running `gradle :SubProjectB:build` from the root project's directory?

The end goals are to make it easier to use gradle from the command line, and to get functional default tasks on the sub-projects. That way I should be able to double-click a project Eclipse's Gradle tasks list, and have it run the default tasks as though it were running the tasks from root.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use `composite builds`. Let say you are at `SubProjectA` and want to build against `SubProjectB`. The you can execute the command below:

```
gradle --include-build ../anotherDirectory/SubProjectB run
```

`SubProjectB` will build first and then `SubProjectA`.